Amplifying an electrostatic charge / field
Amplifying an electrostatic charge / field
I understand that the strength of a magnetic field can be amplified by coiling a wire around an iron bar (along with using DC voltage)
, creating an electromagnet. Is there a comparable technique to boost the strength of an electrostatic field or charge, perhaps by using a similar method with a readily available material?”

Magnetic field is not amplified by the iron bar, it is instead routed by it. It is made stronger in one place at the cost of making it weaker in another place. The reason you can do it is essentially because iron, like some other materials, can be 'magnetically polarized', i.e. its magnetization responds non-trivially to applied magnetic field. This is typically described by Magnetic Susceptibility.
You are interested in the electric equivalent of this, so you are looking for materials where electric polarization responds non-trivially to applied electric field. The relevant physical quantity here is polarizability. This becomes important in some dynamic cases (e.g. a lot of optics and non-linear optics is concerned with it), but for statics you probably want to look at Capacitors, where polarizable dielectrics are used to get higher capacitance.

Famously, water molecules have electric dipole and thus water can be polarized. E.g. here water responds to non-homogeneous electric field https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZYyvOyMowc
